# Erlang: List Comprehension to an Existing List

Tags: list, datetime, erlang, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a new list via a list comprehension but want those new values to be included in an existing list.

More specifically, I am try to create a string out of the date and will have some string formatting between the values ( a dash - ).  The existing list will be a template if you will with the dash.

Here is what I have so far:

```
{Date, Time} = erlang:universaltime().
DateList = tuple_to_list(Date).
DateListString = [ integer_to_list(X) || X < DateList ].
DateListStringConcatenate = lists:flatten(DateListString).
```

The result should be something along
"20101121"

But, what I want is
"2010-11-21"

So I am thinking about the DateListString comprehension "comprehending" to an existing list with "-" after the first and second element.

Any suggestions accompanied with concrete code samples much appreciated.

Comment: You are absolutely Roberto... Sorry about that .. .was not the intent.  But, I did instead give points to every answer that I thought was good.  Rectifying the accept part now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
1> {{Y,M,D},_} = erlang:universaltime().
{{2010,11,21},{16,42,56}}
2> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p-~p-~p", [Y,M,D])).
"2010-11-21"
```

Comment: Well done Roberto.  More concise than Damodharan so will select it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it in a list comprehension then you could do the following:

```
{Date, Time} = erlang:universaltime().
DateList = tuple_to_list(Date).
DateListString = [ [$- | integer_to_list(X)] || X <- DateList ].
[_ | DateListStringConcatenate] = lists:flatten(DateListString).
```

Roberto's is a better/more efficient solution to this but in case you wondered how you might do it with a list comprehension this would be one way.

Comment: I love how pattern matching reveals interesting solutions to problems.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy... yes, definitely interesting to see. Added a point for your answer.

Comment: I would not write that Roberto's solution is more efficient solution unless benchmark it but io_lib is well known that it is not performance champion. I would bet to your solution personally because imagine what io_lib have to do. You can improve performance when change `lists:flatten/1` to `lists:append/1`. Even faster in BEAM should be `integer_to_list(Year) ++ "-" ++ integer_to_list(Month) ++ "-" ++ integer_to_list(Day)`. In Native can be handcrafted solution better. And NIF will rule of course.

Comment: Hynek... thanks for the commment.  always appreciate your insights on performance and efficiency.  also liked your perspective on lists vs proplists for getting a value (sergio's blog)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, but I feel that it is not an elegant one. Also, it does not use list comprehension.

```
1> {Date, Time} = erlang:universaltime().
{{2010,11,21},{14,51,23}}
2> DateList = tuple_to_list(Date).
[2010,11,21]
3> DateListString = lists:zipwith(fun(X,Y) -> integer_to_list(X) ++ Y end, DateList, ["-","-",""]).           
["2010-","11-","21"]
4> DateListStringConcatenate = lists:flatten(DateListString).
"2010-11-21"
```

Comment: Thanks... I was looking into zipwith just now and might go with it if someone does not come up with a more elegant or list comprehension solution